# Use two or more locale translations at same time in same page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, locale, laravel-blade, multilingual

I am using Laravel 8. How I can show translation for two or more lang on the same page. Please see the image below:

[image]

Any idea how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a third argument to the `__` function.

For example:

```
{{ __('Address', [], 'en') }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

Definition of that helper function you can find [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L864).